# How to return specific data for same id using SQL query?

Tags: sql, database

I have a below table with the columns id and status.

[image]

I tried multiple times to query the above table to retrieve the result like below but I failed.

[image]

Comment: What is the logic here? Is it if an `ID` has at least one `Unapproved` record then that `id` is considered `Unapproved`? Also, please paste your data as text and not as a screenshot so we can replicate if need be.

Comment: do you wanna have the last status or do you wanna have enabled if every row with id is enable or disable otherways ?

Comment: @JNevill yes, if an ID has at least one Unapproved record then that id needs to be considered to be Unapproved. Sorry for the screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Max()` here since `Unapproved` is alphabetically higher than `Approved`:

```
SELECT id, max(status) FROM yourtable GROUP BY id;
```